# Sqlalchemy include empty relationship with join and contains_eager

Tags: python, json, filter, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have 2 models Recording and Recording_results like so

```
class Recording(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'recordings'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = Column(String, nullable=False)

    language_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('languages.id'), nullable=False)
    language = relationship("Language", back_populates="recordings")

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="recordings")

    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False,
                        default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())
    deletedd_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'id: {}'.format(self.id)

User.recordings = relationship("Recording", order_by=Recording.id, back_populates="user")
Language.recordings = relationship("Recording", order_by=Recording.id, back_populates="language")


class RecordingResult(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'recording_results'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    is_with_dictionary = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    result = Column(String, nullable=True)
    run_time = Column(Float, default=0.0)

    recording_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('recordings.id'), nullable=False)
    recording = relationship("Recording", back_populates="recording_results", lazy="joined")

    speech_service_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('speech_services.id'), nullable=False)
    speech_service = relationship("SpeechService", back_populates="recording_results")

    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False,
                        default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())
    deletedd_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'id: {}'.format(self.id)

Recording.recording_results = relationship("RecordingResult", order_by="desc(RecordingResult.id)", back_populates="recording", lazy="joined")
SpeechService.recording_results = relationship("RecordingResult", order_by=RecordingResult.id, back_populates="speech_service")
```

I need to get list of items of recording that uncluding recording_results in it and with conditions(Recording.user_id == id, Recording.deletedd==None, RecordingResult.deletedd==None)

I used this query

```
db.session.query(Recording).filter(Recording.user_id == id, Recording.deletedd_at == None).order_by(Recording.id.desc()).join(Recording.recording_results).options(contains_eager(Recording.recording_results)).filter(RecordingResult.deletedd_at == None).all()
```

And it filter out but seems like the join method does not include recording with empty recording_results relationship

The result i print out to json using marshmallow

My result:

```
{
        "id": 4,
        "filename": "15615378415768423_test.txt",
        "language_id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "recording_results": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "is_with_dictionary": true,
                "result": "test5",
                "run_time": 1200.2,
                "recording_id": 4,
                "speech_service_id": 2
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2019-06-26T08:30:41.591410+00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "filename": "15615371606083994_test.txt",
        "language_id": 2,
        "user_id": 2,
        "recording_results": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "is_with_dictionary": true,
                "result": "test1",
                "run_time": 1500.2,
                "recording_id": 2,
                "speech_service_id": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "is_with_dictionary": false,
                "result": "test2",
                "run_time": 1600.2,
                "recording_id": 2,
                "speech_service_id": 3
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2019-06-26T08:19:20.628205+00:00"
    }
```

Expecting result:

```
{
        "id": 5,
        "filename": "15616009750201173_test.txt",
        "language_id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "recording_results": [],
        "created_at": "2019-06-27T02:02:55.035810+00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "filename": "15615378415768423_test.txt",
        "language_id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "recording_results": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "is_with_dictionary": true,
                "result": "test5",
                "run_time": 1200.2,
                "recording_id": 4,
                "speech_service_id": 2
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2019-06-26T08:30:41.591410+00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "filename": "15615371606083994_test.txt",
        "language_id": 2,
        "user_id": 2,
        "recording_results": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "is_with_dictionary": false,
                "result": "test2",
                "run_time": 1600.2,
                "recording_id": 2,
                "speech_service_id": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "is_with_dictionary": true,
                "result": "test1",
                "run_time": 1500.2,
                "recording_id": 2,
                "speech_service_id": 4
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2019-06-26T08:19:20.628205+00:00"
    }
```

How do i include empty relationship in the join query too ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` like the one produced by

```
join(Recording.recording_results)
```

will only produce a row when a matching row exists on both sides of the join.

A `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, produced by `Query.outerjoin()` will include rows on the left that have no matching row on the right, so changing the join type helps, if you have no additional predicates that use the right table.

In fact you do, but it sort of "works" as is, because it is an `IS NULL` check. Still, its proper place is the `ON` clause in this case:

```
outerjoin(RecordingResult, and_(Recording.recording_results, RecordingResult.deletedd_at == None))
```

which replaces the use of `filter()`.

Comment: i got sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Expected mapped entity or selectable/table as join target error,  why it doesn't regconize recording result as a join map ?

Comment: Hmm, will have a look a tad bit later at what's going on.

Comment: Yeah the error only show with your example using ON clause if i change join to outerjoin only then it worked

Comment: Resolved, when using an explicit `ON` clause, the target should be what the error says — `RecordingResult` in this case.